# Is there a way to use the ARC migration tool on a per-file basis only?

Tags: ios, xcode, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

I've discovered some inconsistencies when using the ARC migration tool multiple times on the whole project.

For example:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [ivar release], ivar = nil;
}
```

The first iteration convertis this to:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    ivar = nil;
}
```

The second iteration gets rid of -dealloc alltogether. Assuming that it makes no sense to set ivars to nil in -dealloc since ARC does that anyways automatically, it's strange that ARC leaves the `ivar = nil` in the first place.

To prevent possibly strange bugs, is there a way to use the ARC migration tool only for one special file rather than the whole project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you choose Edit > Refactor > Convert to Objective-C ARC, a sheet opens with a list of your project's targets. Click the disclosure triangle next to a target to show a list of source files. From there you can choose the files to convert to ARC.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe so. 
You don't have to do much to "convert" a project to use ARC support.
Remove all dealloc, release, and nil (where needed) calls.

No strange bugs should occur after the conversion, since the compiler takes care of everything for you and not buggy XCode.

Comment: I've found it very useful to hand convert all my projects.  It's gives me a nice refresher over what is happening since there will be small issues to take care of.